# How to replace string with another array string in php

Tags: php

Actually I want to convert the string that I enter in input text, and then compare to another array.. See scenario below:

First, I enter this type of string in input text: `acgta`
Second, I want to replace the "acgta" to the "TGCAT" which is `a=T, c=G, g=C`

This is code:

```
$data = "acgta";
$s = str_split($data);

$d = array("a" => "T","g" => "C","c" => "G","t" => "A");

foreach($d as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo str_replace($key1,$value1,$data);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = "acgta";
echo str_replace(array('a', 'c', 'g', 't'), array('T', 'G', 'C', 'A'), $data);
```

or

```
$data = "acgta";
echo strtr($data, 'acgt', 'TGCA');
```

Take a look at the PHP manual pages for:

- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)
- [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr)

Comment: `strtr` is by far the best way for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `strtr` function. This is pretty self-explanatory if you read the PHP doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
$data = "acgta";
$d = array("a" => "T","g" => "C","c" => "G","t" => "A");

echo strtr($data, $d);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with array elements.  See below:

```
$data = "acgta";
$fromArr = array('a', 'g', 'c', 't');
$toArr = array('T', 'C', 'G', 'A');

echo str_replace($fromArr, $toArr, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can simply use this:

```
$string = "acgta";
$from = array('a', 'g', 'c', 't');
$to = array('T', 'C', 'G', 'A');
$string = str_replace($from, $to, $string);
```

#### Or in a simple way:

```
$string = "acgta";
$string = str_replace(array('a', 'g', 'c', 't'), array('T', 'C', 'G', 'A'), $string);
```

Comment: `+1` Lolz, no other way... Is there any?

Comment: Covered pretty good in here.  Just a race to the finish all within a minute or two!

Comment: Rightly said... Speed matters! But I need quality!

Comment: @rid No use of using `preg_replace` for this simple stuff.